# How to use Core Data relationship?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

In my app I have 3 related entities. Athlete, Exercise, and Exercise Score.

Athlete has a to-many relationship with Exercise. It's inverse is whosExercise.
Exercise has a to-many relationship with exercise score. It's inverse is whichExercise.

I want to perform a fetch request where I get all the exercise scores for an athlete. How would I get that? Do I need another relationship between Athlete and Exercise Scores, or is that redundant? If it is, how would I use exercise as a predicate for my request?

Answer (score 0):

If Exercise has a relationship to Athlete, then you should be able to do something like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.athlete = @%", currentAthlete];
```

and then just:

```
[Exercise fetchByPredicate:currentAthletePredicate];
```

Should be it.

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand, you need to select all ExerciseScore for Athlete, but Athlete does not have direct relationship with ExerciseScore table.

SLQ Query for this may looks like :

```
 Select *
 from ExerciseScore
 where IDScore in (select IDScore
                     from  Exercise
                    where IDExercise in ( select IDExercise
                                           from Athlete
                                        )
                  )
```

But in Core Data you can't operate SLQ Queries.
Try this approach.

1.Fetch all Exercise for Athlete:

```
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Exercise"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.athlete = @%", currentAthlete];
request.predicate=predicate;
NSArray *athleteExercises = [self.managedObjectContext  executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

2.Iterate throughout array of Exercises to get all Exercise score for each Exercise.

```
NSMutableArray *allScores = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];;
for (Exercise *exercise in athleteExercises) {

  if ([exercise.scores count]>0) {
     [allScores addObjectsFromArray:[exercise.scores allObjects]; //exercise.scores must be NSSet type
  }
}
```

`allScores` array now contain All `ExerciseScore` objects for particular `Athlete.`

Answer (score 0):

Predicates can have key paths:

```
@"whichExercise.whosExercise = %@",athlete
```

Or, if you have the athlete already, don't do a fetch request, just get the scores via the relationship properties.